# Is it possible to set an arbitrary form id before submitting manually with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I made this really interesting piece of code that submits a form via AJAX only if the form carries an ID.

```
$(document).delegate('form', 'submit', function(event) {

    var $form = $(this);
    var id = $form.attr('id');

    //if form does not have an id, then submit it without ajax!
    if(typeof id == 'undefined'){
        $form.submit();
    }else{

$.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize(), function(response) {  
          //response stuff  

    });

    event.preventDefault(); 
 }
});
```

But the problem now is when i manually make an ajax form submit call from a different function, and pass the values manually, it submits the form regularly without Ajax. How can i add an ID to this ajax call before submitting the form to TestServlet if the form does not exist in the html?

```
//is it possible to add a form id before doing the ajax call below?
         $.ajax({
// Maybe possible to add form id here?
              url: 'TestServlet',
              data: {
                  commentID: commentID,
                  comment: "lol"
              },
              type: 'post',
              success: function(data){
                window.location = data.url;
              } 

          });
```

Comment: Can you explain bit more, not sure if anyone can understand what you're asking?

Comment: You should probably be using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and not `delegate`

Comment: i need the code to stay the same, because of how everything is structured. All i need to know is how to add a form id to the ajax call shown in the last piece of code. Or whether that is even possible?

Comment: How is a form being submitted when you make a different Ajax call? Unclear what you are asking. That second chunk of code should not trigger that first code snipplet.

Comment: are you trying to submit form using non-ajax if no id and ajax if has id?

Comment: yes correct @YongQuan

Comment: Yeah i didn't really understand that either @epascarello, but it does trigger. Maybe because of the delegate

Comment: There is no form submission so I am betting it has to do with the action that triggers the method you are calling. Do you use a button?

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte no way you can do it within an ajax call. You need to check existence of form id (and add id if no id) before the second chunk of code.

Comment: @epascarello it triggers from another function when the user finishes editing an input by clicking away. There is no surrounding form, or a submit action. 

YongQuan maybe there is a way to add the form id outside the ajax call?

Comment: What triggers the initial function to run?

Comment: A user clicks on an edit icon for a comment, and the comment gets converted into a textarea that the user can edit. All i did was add that ajax call to the end of that function that allows user to edit a comment and it triggers perfectly fine.

Comment: Do you cancel the default action when they click the edit icon?

Comment: no, there is no form surrounding the edit function because i need to pass the values manually. The first piece of code, gets triggered when the ajax code below it runs. You can try it yourself, it works

Comment: That code is not going to trigger the submit handler that is why I am suggesting whatever you are clicking is submitting a form. Cancel the click and see if it stops firing. You can even test it for yourself, copy the Ajax call and set values and run it in the console. That delegate line is not going to fire.

Comment: well it does man, you can look at all the code here, there are no other triggers
https://codeshare.io/ayDdn9

Answer (score 1):

Your first piece of code tells me the following:

When your form has an **html id** attribute you submit it with AJAX using the **url from action attribute**.

When your form have no html id attribute, you make a normal submit, which uses the **url from action attribute** also.

So no matter which way you submit, you use a single action, **it has nothing to do with your form id**.

**Then why within your second piece of code would you set a form id if there is no form at all?**

Just work on creating a right url like below, for example:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'TestServlet/{possibleID}',
   data: {
     commentID: commentID,
     comment: "lol"
   },
   type: 'post',
   success: function(data){
     window.location = data.url;
   }     
});
```

Comment: I see. That's helpful! So i should check if the action attribute is also undefined and then set the id & action manually if they are not defined. So placing the 'url' value in that ajax call would be meaningless right?

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte stop lol. You are messing things up. Tell me what you really wanna do, forget about ids and action attributes, just think what your goal here.

Comment: submitting the values manually via ajax... But it triggers my other damn delegate function..

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte I may know your problem then. Show me how you reach that ajax call, where you click. The code you are showing is not enough.

Comment: I just added the ajax call to the end of another function is all. The two pieces of code that are important here i have already added.. there is nothing else going on, you can see here:  
https://codeshare.io/ayDdn9

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte you are calling that ajax function with a blur event?! Is that right?

Comment: Hmm i guess so, but a very specific blur event that wouldn't happen anywhere else on the page..
 $input.on("blur", switchToSpan);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146899/discussion-between-ramon-marques-and-jonathan-laliberte).